# How to solve the IE 8 table row background image bug

Tags: css, debugging, internet-explorer-8, background-image, css-tables

Anyone can help me solve [this problem](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/tiling-background-ie/)?
The solution doesn't work on IE 8.

In a nutshell - if you apply a background picture to a table row the background
is applied to the inner cells.

Comment: What do you want? the solution provided is to get a background image across the entire row (TR), including the TD's.  If you want a different background on the TDs, just specify one (color and/or image)

Comment: as i said - the solution doesent work on IE 8.

i"m searching for a solution for IE8

Comment: To be honest, a little more detail about what you are actually trying to achieve would be very useful here. Hence scunliffe asking the question of "What do you want?"... 

We are trying to help after all, so the more detail, the better :o)

Answer (score 2):

To get a background image on a table row that works in IE8 (also Safari and Chrome) you have to apply a background image to the table cells of the row rather than the table row.

So, for example, taking the following table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cellFirst">First cell</td>
    <td class="cellMiddle">Middle cell</td>
    <td class="cellMiddle">Middle cell</td>
    <td class="cellLast">Last cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And applying the following CSS:

```
td.cellFirst {
  background: url('my-image.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

td.cellMiddle {
  background: url('my-image.png') 50% 0 no-repeat;
}

td.cellLast {
  background: url('my-image.png') 100% 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Would give you a 'row' with a background image. The my-image.png which is the row background is used in each of the cells.

The only thing we are doing differently is changing the background position of the image. Obviously for the first cell we start at the left, so 0. For the middle cells the image is positioned at 50%. This would hide the left hand edge of the image. And finally we position the image of the last cell at 100% which starts it from the right edge of the image.

There we go, a background image on a row.

Answer (score 1):

Much better solution is to do the following:
Add `position:relative` to the TR and set the `background-image:none` on the TD.

Reportedly works in all but Mac Safari. To compensate for this, wrap the `TR` block in a `TBODY` block and give the `TBODY` block the background ;)

Oh yeah!

Answer (score 0):

Add 'background-image:none' to td inside that tr.

Answer (score 0):

Does assigning the "row" image to the tables with background position rely on the columns being equal in size?  What if the size of the image doesn't take up the whole row? I have the following CSS that works as expected in FF:

```
tr.selected { background: #0842C4 url(/my/background/image) repeat-y top right; }
```

The image is a gradient and the color starts at `#0842C4`.

And to make the task more challenging, the HTML is a popup menu created by JavaScript that I don't control, so changing the table is not an option.